# JCrop big images issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

Is it possible to set some maxWidth and maxHeight in order to crop big images?
I found out maxSize in documentation, but it is only for selection area. Also I tried trueSize

```
function initJCrop(){
    // Create variables (in this scope) to hold the API and image size
    var jcrop_api,
        boundx,
        boundy,

        // Grab some information about the preview pane
        $preview = $('#preview-pane'),
        $pcnt = $('#preview-pane .preview-container'),
        $pimg = $('#preview-pane .preview-container img'),

        xsize = $pcnt.width(),
        ysize = $pcnt.height();

    //console.log('init',[xsize,ysize]);
    $('#imageEdit').Jcrop({
      onChange: updatePreview,
      onSelect: updatePreview,
      aspectRatio: 220 / 55,


    },  function(){
      // Use the API to get the real image size
      var bounds = this.getBounds();
      boundx = bounds[0];
      boundy = bounds[1];
      // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
      jcrop_api = this;

      jcrop_api.animateTo([ 120,120,20,20 ]);
      jcrop_api.trueSize([200, 100])
      // Move the preview into the jcrop container for css positioning
      $preview.appendTo(jcrop_api.ui.holder);

    });
```

Now my Images are like this one. They are out of bounds of modal:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer.
You should use boxHeight and boxWidth options.
Like this:

```
$('#imageEdit').Jcrop({
      onChange: updatePreview,
      onSelect: updatePreview,
      aspectRatio: 220 / 55,
      boxWidth: 350

    },  function(){
      // Use the API to get the real image size
      var bounds = this.getBounds();
      boundx = bounds[0];
      boundy = bounds[1];
      // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
      jcrop_api = this;

      jcrop_api.animateTo([ 120,120,20,20 ]);
    //  jcrop_api.trueSize([200, 100])
      // Move the preview into the jcrop container for css positioning
      $preview.appendTo(jcrop_api.ui.holder);

    });
```